# Error while saving data in sql from R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to insert data in sql table with action button from r shiny app. I have 5 columns in my db and I just want to insert data in one column(status) of db only. When I update the selectInput, the selected choice should be saved in the database.
I am using-

```
updateSelectInput(session,
                        paste0("selecter_", i),
                        input[[paste0("selecter_", i)]],
                        label = NULL)

sql_update <-  paste0("INSERT INTO tbl1 (status) VALUES(",paste(input[[paste0('`selecter_`', i)]], sep = "/n"),");")
      DBI::dbSendStatement(conn = pms_conn, statement = sql_update)
      DBI::dbDisconnect(pms_conn)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what error your are getting? This will improve your chances of getting a reply.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error- "Warning: Error in : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 [1136]"